# Fourier Sine Transform of $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ equal $s^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

Tags: fourier-transform

Using that the fact the Laplace transform of $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ is $\gamma{\frac{1}{2}}p^{\frac{-1}{2}}$, show that Fourier Sine Transform of $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ equal $s^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

I don't know how to go about this. I showed it using Fourier Cosine Transform but don't know how to do it for FST.

$\gamma$=gamma

Comment: The Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}$, there is no Euler-Mascheroni constant involved.

Comment: I showed it using FCT by:  $\mathcal F_c (x^{\frac{-1}{2}})=\sqrt \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} x^{\frac{-1}{2}}(cos(sx)-isin(sx))dx$ b/c  $\mathcal F_c (f(x))=i\mathcal F_s (f(x))$

Comment: Which then becomes: $\mathcal F_c (x^{\frac{-1}{2}})= \sqrt \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} x^{\frac{-1}{2}} * e^{isx} dx $ After this we can use Laplace transform for $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ which is what we wanted. I feel like beyond this is pretty self explanatory. I don't know how to do this method for Fourier Sine Transform

Comment: It asks for me to show the Fourier Sine Transforms of x^{\frac{-1}{2}} equals s^{\frac{-1}{2}} so I think I can show it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

By the Laplace transform,
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\omega\,ds}{(s^2+\omega^2)\sqrt{\pi s}}=\frac{2\omega}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{s^4+\omega^2}$$
and the last integral is straightforward to compute through the residue theorem. That proves that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is an eigenfunction for the Fourier sine transform.

Answer (score 0):

Let be 
$$\mathcal F_c\{f(t)\}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty f(t)\cos(st)\,\mathrm dt=F_c(s)$$
the Fourier Cosine transform of $f(t)$ and
$$\mathcal F_c\{f(t)\}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty f(t)\cos(st)\,\mathrm dt=F_s(s)$$
the Fourier Cosine transform of $f(t)$ and let be $$\mathcal L\{f(t)\}=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt}\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-(x+is)t}\,\mathrm dt=F(x+is)$$
the Laplace Transform of $f(t)$. For $x=0,\, p=is$ and then
$$F(is)=\int_0^\infty f(t)\cos(st)\,\mathrm dt-i\int_0^\infty f(t)\sin(st)\,\mathrm dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big(F_c(s)-iF_s(s)\Big)$$
So if you know that $\mathcal L\{t^{-1/2}\}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}$, for $p=is$ we find
$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{is}}$ and observing that
$$i^{-1/2}=e^{-i\pi/4}=\cos(\pi/4)-i\sin(\pi/4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-i)$$
we have
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-i)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\Big(F_c(s)-iF_s(s)\Big)
$$
and equating real and imaginary parts we find

> $$
> F_c(s)=F_s(s)=s^{-1/2}
> $$